# Is there a way to show custom message on UI if user account is disabled in azure?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement to disable a user account in azure so that user is not able to login to the application. And when I login with the disabled user credentials it should show a custom message "Your account has been deactivated by Admin." instead of the standard message "Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, and try again". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use language customization to change the message. The localization id is UserMessageIfUserAccountDisabled.

This is the reference to loc Ids
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-or-sign-in-error-messages

This is the reference to localization in Azure AD B2C
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow